# Task.Factory.StartNew() followed by Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I would like to know what the point is of creating and starting a task, followed by a call to wait for the task. It's always been my belief that the point of tasks is for asynchronous programming, but this seems to just create more resources for a synchronous operation.

```
var task1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckMaps());
task1.Wait();

var task2 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckTicker());
task2.Wait();
```

Here are a few resources I found while trying to find an answer:

[SO: ...calling Task.Wait()...after an asynchronous operation...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31419119/4649822) - results of task.Wait() and task.Result() after task declaration.

[Stephen Toub - Task.Wait and Inlining](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining) - Task.Wait() can pull a task out of the scheduler and execute it inline. (In this case it wouldn't apply because the task has already started.)

[SO: Memory Barrier Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932271/4649822) - Creating a task creates memory barriers.

These resources mostly answered my concerns, but I can't help but feel like I'm breaking something when I replace all these tasks with standard method calls.

Is there something that specifically `Task.Factory.StartNew()` does in the background that would be significantly different than a regular method call?

Comment: No; you should never do that.

Comment: I'm working on the maintainability of an app in the office, and `Task.Factory.StartNew()` calls are littered everywhere without any real explanation of why they are required. I don't understand why the original programmer went through all the extra effort just to take up more resources...

Comment: Probably because they didn't understand threading or async.

Comment: I wrote the first answer you linked to. That's a pretty exhaustive list and it's an exact duplicate. Closing.

Comment: @usr yeah... I read the answer over and over but I needed to make sure that `Task.Factory.StartNew` wasn't doing something I was unaware of.

Comment: If you ever find out more edit the answer. Let's face it, that guy was misunderstanding something.